# How can I improve my validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

How to improve my validation in JavaScript?

Namely I am wondering whether some parts of code can be shortened, improved, or removed althogether.

I don't want to change the ES5 syntax because so far I am not familiar with Es6 syntax.

I also want to avoid using jQuery.

This is my validation code:
https://codepen.io/RobotHabanera/pen/NWbKJLe

```
   var form = document.querySelector('form');
    var errormessage = document.querySelector('.error-message');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // musimy zalożyć czy formularz jest poprawnie wypełniony czy nie
        var errors = [];
        errormessage.innerHTML = '';
        var clearAllParagraphsAtTheStart = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group p');
        clearAllParagraphsAtTheStart.forEach(function(item) {
            item.innerHTML = '';
        });
        // sprawdzić czy walidacja bedzie działać
        for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
            var field = form.elements[i];
            switch (field.name) {
                case 'email':
                    // najpierw negujemy funkcje hasMonkeyInFiled i jesli negacja przebiegnie prawidłowo to wykona się prawa strona komunikatu && bo
                    // jesli negacja nie przebiegnie prawidłowo to linijka z prawej sterony sie nie wykona.
                    !hasMonkeyInFiled(field) && errors.push({
                        email: 'Email musi posiadać znak @'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'name':
                    !hasMoreThanTwoChars(field) && errors.push({
                        name: 'Twoje imię jest za krótkie'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'surname':
                    !hasMoreThanSixChars(field) && errors.push({
                        surname: 'Twoje nazwisko jest za krótkie'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'pass1':
                    !hasCorrectPassword(field, form.elements[i + 1]) && errors.push({
                        pass1: 'Hasła nie są takie same lub puste'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'pass2':
                    !hasCorrectPassword(field, form.elements[i - 1]) && errors.push({
                        pass2: 'Hasła nie są takie same lub puste'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'agree':
                    !isChecked(field) && errors.push({
                        agree: 'Musisz zaakceptować warunki'
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (errors.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
            errors = errors.filter(function(v, i, a) {
                return a.indexOf(v) === i;
            });
            errors.forEach(function(item, index) {
                // wklej wartość klucza z tablicy errors gdzie nazwa klucza jest równa wartości danego data-validation bierzącego inputa z pętli
                var currentKey = Object.keys(errors[index]);
                var currentValue = Object.values(errors[index]);
                var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-group input');
                inputs.forEach(function(item, index) {
                    if (item.dataset.validation == currentKey) {
                        var elementP = document.createElement('p');
                        elementP.innerHTML = currentValue;
                        item.after(elementP);
                    }
                });
                /* errormessage.append(elementP);  */
            });
        }
    });

    function hasCorrectPassword(field1, field2) {
        if (hasMatch(field1, field2) && hasNumberChar(field1) && hasNumberChar(field1)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // paramertr 'field' to jest input element
    function hasMonkeyInFiled(field) {
        return field.value.indexOf('@') > -1;
    }
    // input ma wiecej niz 6 znakow
    function hasMoreThanSixChars(field) {
        return field.value.length > 6;
    }
    // input ma wiecej niz 2 znaki
    function hasMoreThanTwoChars(field) {
        return field.value.length > 2;
    }
    // checkbox musi byc zaznaczony
    function isChecked(field) {
        return field.checked;
    }
    // pierwsze i drugie hasło są identyczne ale nie puste
    function hasMatch(field1, field2) {
        // jak sprawdzic czy nie sa puste
        if (field1.value.length && field1.value.length) {
            return field1.value == field2.value;
        }
        return false;
    }
    // Warunek dla chętnych. Dodatkowe. Hasło ma mieć co najmniej 6 znaków (w tym co najmniej jedną liczbę i jedną literę)
    function hasNumberChar(field) {
        var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        var hasNumber = false;
        numbers.forEach(function(number) {
            if (field.value.indexOf(number) > -1) {
                hasNumber = true;
            }
        });
        return hasNumber;
    }

    function hasLetterChar(field) {
        var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
        var hasChar = false;
        chars.forEach(function(char) {
            if (field.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(chars) > -1) {
                hasChar = true;
            }
        });
        return hasChar;
    }
    // input ma wiecej niz 5 znakow
    function hasMoreThanFiveChars(field) {
        return field.value.length > 5;
    }

    function isPangram(string) {
        string.replace(/ /g, '');
        for (var i = 0; i < string.trim().length; i++) {
            var array = [];
            var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
            chars.forEach(function(char) {
                if (char == string.substr(string[i], 1)) {} else {
                    array.push(string[i])
                }
            });
        }
        if (array.length) {}
        // bierze pierwszą litere z tablicy i jedzie tą literą po wszystkich znakach tekstu 
        string.replace(/ /g, '');
        chars.forEach(function(char) {
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
                if (char == string[i]) {
                    console.log('jest');
                } else {
                    console.log('nie ma');
                }
            }
        });
    };

    function isPangram(string) {
        string.replace(/ /g, '');
        var array = [];
        var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
        chars.forEach(function(char) {
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                // każda litera alfabetu ma przejechać po tekście 
                if (char == string[i]) {
                    array.push(string[i]);
                } else {}
            }
            if (array.length > 0) {
                console.log('jest')
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: The thing I noticed is two `hasMoreThanSixChars` and `hasMoreThanTwoChars` are basically the same and you can make it a more generic function which receives length as well. For validation there are some libraries like `yup` which you can use, or at least take a look at and see what methods they have and how they work and how they think. The other thing is that maybe storing your form values in an object give you an extra layer of abstraction which may help.

Comment: ok - thanks, I will check out that yup library

Answer (score -1):

You should look at using regex for at least your tests for numbers or letters:

```
// match a letter, number or underscore
string.match(/\w/);
// Match a-z and A-Z (the i at the end makes case insensitive) - this could replace hasLetterChar()
string.match(/[a-z]/i);
// match a number - that could replace hasNumberChar()
string.match(/\d/);
```

Of course you can combine these to make a total test in one go. Actually, that would be better, together with /^ $/, that will make the test only pass if it matches from start to end of the string. That way you will not get any unexpected input.

Comment: Given that OP seems to be using a non Latin character set [this won't work](https://regexr.com/5lae5)

Comment: @liam True, but I just answered his question: how can I shorten my code. He has a hasLetterChar() and a hasNumvberChar(), where he tests for a-z and 0-9 resp. This is wat the regex replaces. That is correct. It is obvious that Piotr has other chars in his language, but I don't see that in his code. Perhaps he writes it for another purpose?

Comment: Actually, I don't see him use hasLetterChar() at all. So the simplest answer to his question is: delete that function :-)